# How can I extract a part(number) of a string which contains special characters

Tags: python, split, special-characters, strip

I hope that you can help me to extract numbers from strings.

I get a string in two possible ways:

1. y = required number e.g. "60"
2. x = required number in a string with special characters and possibly another number at the beginning

This example lists the possible variants for x (x1 - x7),

I need in the end the extracted number:

=> "60" in this case (exeption x3 = 50)

I try to use regex split und strip function. But unfortunately it doesn't work for all variants:

What do I have to change so that it works for all variants?

```
import re

b=[]
y="60"

# x-x2: split and strip function is working => b="60"
x = "5: 60 USD"
x1= "5. $60 USD"
x2= "5- 60 USD"

# x3-x7: split and strip function is NOT working
x3 ="5: 50 USD"
x4 ="5 : 60 USD"
x5 ="5 . 60 USD"
x6 ="5 - $60 USD"
x7 ="5:$60 USD"


a,b = re.split('5: |5. |5-',x)

b = b.upper().strip(' -§$%&€ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:')

print(b)

#b should be 60 each time (exeption x3 = 50)
```

Comment: Don't you simply need all the characters that are numbers after the first character?

Comment: How do you know that the 60 is the number you want and the 5 isn't? What rule or logic tells you that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re


x = re.sub('[^0-9][.]{0,1}[^0-9]', " ", x)
x = re.sub('USD', "", x)

try:
    b = x.split()[1]
except:
    b = ".".join(x.split(".")[1:])
```

Full code:

```
import re

b=[]
y="60"

# x-x2: split and strip function is working => b="60"
x0 = "5: 60 USD"
x1= "5. $60 USD"
x2= "5- 60 USD"

# x3-x7: split and strip function is NOT working
x3 ="5: 50 USD"
x4 ="5 : 60 USD"
x5 ="5 . 60 USD"
x6 ="5 - $60 USD"
x7 ="5:$60.000 USD"

x_list = [x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7]

for x in x_list:

    print ("raw "+x)

    x = re.sub('[^0-9][.]{0,1}[^0-9]', " ", x)

    b = x.split()[1]

    print ("clean "+b)
```

Output:

```
raw 5: 60 USD
clean 60
raw 5. $60 USD
clean $60
raw 5- 60 USD
clean 60
raw 5: 50 USD
clean 50
raw 5 : 60 USD
clean 60
raw 5 . 60 USD
clean 60
raw 5 - $60 USD
clean 60
raw 5:$60.000 USD
clean 60.000
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. But it doens't work well. I tried to change x.split( "=") to x.split (" "). But this didn't work for all variants as well.

Comment: Sorry I am tired ahaha. This should make it isn't it?

Comment: Yes perfect. This is a pretty nice code. I like it :-)

Comment: Cool! You can switch the answer tag in case you think that one is more advantageous ;)

Comment: The only problem I have, if I have got x8 = "5: $60.000 USD". It returns just 60. If you can help me in this case then I will definitely change the answer tag :-)

Comment: Great, thank you a lot for this work and your time. It works pretty fine for all variants that i currently know. :-):-):-)

Comment: Maybe one point more. In rare cases I get something like: x9="5.60.000USD" That would be the ice of the cake if we get an improved code for this. But i guess thats difficult to handle.

Comment: oh sorry for this.

Comment: do you think the problem is solvable? Or will the effort be too big for that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your examples aren't exhaustive, but this works for the examples given:

```
result = int(''.join([ch for ch in x[1:] if ch in '0123456789']))
```

Or:

```
result = int(''.join([ch for ch in x[1:] if ch.isdigit()]))
```

Comment: The `int()` added because I assume you need the number, you can just leave it off if you actually need the numeric string.

Comment: Oh I saw. I tried it with: x8 = "5:$60,5 USD" . In this case It didn't work. How I have to change the code to cover this?

Comment: Have you given this some thought? The provided answer filters out all numbers, but in the counter-example, you want to filter out `60,5` - that's not an integer value, but a floating point value and so you'd need two changes: use `float()` instead of `int` for the conversion and obviously filter out numbers as well as a comma. Also keep in mind that, depending on regional settings, `60,5` won't be a valid float (it would be `60.5` in most cases), so you might have to replace commas in the result with periods first.